# What's the pressure of surrounding of carnot cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

Is it always equal to changing pressure of cylinder?
How is it possible?

Comment: As carnot engine is a reversible heat engine, meaning all the processes involved in it are reversible. Consider the first step, isothermal expansion. So, in this case the pressure of surrounding is infinitesimally less than the system pressure and then the expansion takes place. You can think that above the piston there are beads which together balance the gas pressure. We remove one bead then the pressure of surrounding is infinitesimally less than gas pressure and expansion takes place, and then another bead is removed so on and so forth till we reach desired pressure or volume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First keep in mind that the Carnot cycle is not a practical cycle but establishes an upper limit for the maximum efficiency of any practical heat engine cycle. It is a reversible cycle which means the working fluid (e.g., gas) is always in equilibrium with the surroundings. Consider the following thought experiment for the reversible isothermal expansion process part of the cycle. (See diagrams below).

Let's say you have the gas in a vertically oriented frictionless cylinder and piston. On top of the piston you have a number of weights which, in addition to the external air pressure, provides the external pressure on the system. You now slide a little weight horizontally off of a platform connected to the shaft of the piston and onto another platform along side the cylinder.

Sliding the weight horizontally off the piston would theoretically require very little effort (work) compared to the work done by the gas in raising the remaining weight. In order to carry this process out extremely slowly (reversibly) we can imagine the weight as a pile of sand. We remove the sand one grain at a time causing an infinitely small reduction in external pressure. That results in an infinitely small expansion of the gas, $Adh$, with the product $PV=$ constant. The expansion causes an infinitely small decrease in the gas temperature $dT$ and infinitely small transfer of heat $dQ$ into the gas to bring its temperature and pressure back into equilibrium with the constant temperature surroundings, awaiting the next removal of a weight.

Finally, for the process to be reversible, we must return *both the system and the surroundings exactly to their original state.* Note that after the last weight is removed (top of figure to the right), the platform is above the last weight that was removed. The requires us to take an additional weight from somewhere in the surroundings and place it on our platform to begin the reverse process. The obvious choice in order to return the *system* to its original state (pressure and volume) is to take the first weight that was removed and raise it to the top of the platform. At the completion of the reversed process the system (gas) has been  returned to its original state but the surroundings has been altered as it had to do work to raise the first weight. This demonstrates that in order for the process to be reversible the weights must be infinitesimally small.

Hope this helps.

[image]